# What does I sense a format mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I always understood format as a way something is arranged, but how can you "sense a format"? Maybe it does mean that it was meant that he sense the way things are arranged, like he understands how something is arranged, even after some research I am not very sure.

Here's the context or source rather: http://www.hardwareforums.com/threads/mpeg-4-aac-lc-audio-codec.15613/

Last user posted: "i sense a format coming on in my nervs"

Comment: It's almost 100% certain that "Last user" isn't a native speaker, because (a) he didn't capitalise "i", (b) he can't spell "nerves", (c) idiomatic adverbial clauses associated with ***to sense*** include *in my bones* and *in my water[s]*, but not *in my nerves*. So I wouldn't waste much time thinking about anything he writes in English, since *he doesn't know the language very well at all.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about an invalid utterance generated by a non-native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

*Format* in this context refers to erasing a computer's hard drive.

> I sense a format coming on in my nerves

means that the user anticipates having to erase his hard drive's data.

He has a feeling that he will have to do that soon.

Comment: Is there any other meaning for "I sense a format coming" that are also popular? Sorry if this is off-topic. :C

Comment: No. There are few contexts in which this would make sense. The context of the tech website makes it clear that this is the meaning. Otherwise it would make no sense in that context.